# Columnas de csv al extraer

Tags: python, scraping, scrapy

Un saludo! Estoy extrayendo datos con scrapy y al generar el csv me pone todos los datos de línea en una sola columna, hay manera de que me los traiga separados? aqui está mi código:

'''

```js
from scrapy.item import Field
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
import random

class Cards(Item):
    Price = Field()
    Title = Field()
    Description = Field()

class AmazonC(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'amazon1'
    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36',
        'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 500
    }
    download_delay = 3
    start_urls = {'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=xiaomi&i=mobile&__mk_es_US=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=2TJGL1F8KIRA4&sprefix=xiaom%2Caps%2C340&ref=nb_sb_ss_c_2_5'}

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=r'&page='
            ), follow=True
        ),
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=r'/dp/'
            ), follow=True, callback='parse_items'
        ),
    )

    def limpiarDatos(self, texto):
        texto = texto.replace('/n', ' ').replace('/r', '').replace('/t', ' ').strip()
        return texto

    def parse_items(self, response):
        item = ItemLoader(Cards(), response)
        item.add_xpath('Price', '//span[@class="a-color-price"]/text()', MapCompose(self.limpiarDatos))
        item.add_xpath('Title', '//span[@id="productTitle"]/text()', MapCompose(self.limpiarDatos))
        item.add_xpath('Description', '//table[@id="productDetails_techSpec_section_1"]//tr//td[@class="a-size-base"]/text()', MapCompose(self.limpiarDatos))
        yield item.load_item()
```

Existe la posibilidad de extraer cada dato por columna? Si es posible, cómo lo hago?
Gracias